# "The expression is unused" error when passing { navController.navigate } multiple times [Kotlin]

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've keep getting a "The expression is unused" error. I've been trying to pass the `navController.navigate()` through my `HomeScreen` composable to my `SearchBar` composable.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun App(){
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "home") {
        composable("home")   { HomeScreen(onNavigateToSearch = { navController.navigate("search")},) }
        composable("search") { SearchScreen() }
    }
}

@Composable
fun HomeScreen(onNavigateToSearch: () -> Unit, ) {
    Column { SearchBar(onNavigateToSearch = onNavigateToSearch ) }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SearchBar(
    searchState: MutableState<TextFieldValue> = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) },
    onNavigateToSearch: () -> Unit,
) {
    TextField(
        value = searchState.value,
        onValueChange = { searchState.value = it},
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Search,),
        // ERROR HAPPENS ON THE LINE BELOW
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onSearch = { onNavigateToSearch }),
    )
}
```

I expected the `navController.navigate()` to be activated when the `onSearch` action completes.

Comment: Remove curly braces or add regural ones: `onSearch = onNavigateToSearch` or `onSearch = { onNavigateToSearch() }`